Использование pool(а) подключений к БД. Ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'acquire'
Есть 2 основных модуля, между которыми происходит взаимодействие:
main.py:
class Database:
   def __init__(self, dsn):
       self.dsn = dsn
       self.pool = None

   async def init(self):
       self.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(dsn=self.dsn, command_timeout=60)

   async def query(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
       async with self.pool.acquire() as connection:
           result = await connection.fetch("""query...""", arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
           return result

   async def close(self):
       await self.pool.close()

db = Database(DSN)

async def on_startup():
    # Инициализация базы данных
    await db.init()


async def on_shutdown():
    # Закрытие базы данных
    await db.close()

async def main():
    # Диспетчер
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.include_routers(handlers)
    await dp.start_polling(bot, on_startup=on_startup, on_shutdown=on_shutdown)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
        print('ON')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('OFF')

handler.py:
from main import db, Database

rt = Router()

@rt.message(Command("start"))
async def start(message: types.Message):
    try:
        arg1 = 3
        arg2 = 2
        arg3 = 1
        arg4 = 0

        sql_result = await Database.query(db, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
        print(sql_result)
    except asyncpg.exceptions.UniqueViolationError:
        print("Error")

Проблема заключается в том, что при использовании команды /start в боте появляется ошибка
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'acquire'

Насколько я понимаю, pool остался None, но почему, если после вызова init при старте бота pool уже не должен быть None?
При этом, без использования await здесь: sql_result = await Database.query(db, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) все работает, но появляется предупреждение: coroutine 'Database.query' was never awaited

Почему в main.py не видно импортов? Поправила заголовок и тег вопроса.

Не стал уделять этому внимания. Подразумевал, что импортировал все что нужно

В вопросе тег библиотеки был неправильный, да ещё импортов нет. В классе конечно видно asyncpg, но это надо всматриваться. Задавая вопрос надо быть максимально конкретным.

pool не был инициализирован!?
Проблема в том, что в хендлере обращаешься к классу Database а не экземпляру класса db!
@rt.message(Command("start"))
async def start(message: types.Message):
    try:
        arg1 = 3
        arg2 = 2
        arg3 = 1
        arg4 = 0

        # было так   await Database.query(db, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
        sql_result = await db.query(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
        print(sql_result)
    except asyncpg.exceptions.UniqueViolationError:
        print("Error")

Если обратить внимание на эту функцию:
async def on_startup():
    # Инициализация базы данных
    await db.init()  # именно для экземпляра!


Да, я тоже про это подумал и пробовал, однако результат был такой же

Если после этих изменений, получаешь эту же ошибку, то надо убедиться что инициализация успевает произойти, до использования pool(a). Как это будешь делать?

По сути инициализация не может не успеть произойти в данном примере. Инициализация происходит на этапе запуска поллинга, а использование pool происходит при использовании команды /start. Однако, если проверить значение pool в функции query - оно равно None

Хорошо, реши это - Однако, если проверить значение pool в функции query - оно равно None. А когда решишь сам ответь на свой же вопрос. Успехов!

Проблема в том, что ты не зарегистрировал startup / shutdown обработчики, потому инициализация БД просто не вызвалась.
В aiogram 3.x это делается через регистрацию событий. Пример:
def main() -> None:
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.startup.register(on_startup)
    dp.shutdown.register(on_shutdown)
    return dp.run_polling()

Можно также создать роутер и включить его в диспетчер, регистрируя обработчики событий декораторами.
